# Trying to understand iostat for simple sequential read case

Tags: iostat

I'm looking at the disk I/O performance of a web hosting VPS (virtual server) and I'd like help in understanding the figures that 'iostat' is giving me.

This is my very simple sequential read of the single virtual disk with 'dd':

```
# dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null bs=16k count=102400
6400+0 records in
6400+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 7.91767 s, 13.2 MB/s
```

(13.2MB/s isn't too crash hot IMO.)

The test was conducted when the system was pretty quiet, but there would have still been normal 'quiescent' load while I was running dd.

I ran 'iostat -ktxz 5' during the test; this was the output of the command where the 5-second sample was entirely within the time that 'dd' was running:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda           12030.60     8.00  103.40    1.40 12135.20    36.00   232.27     2.60   23.77   9.54  99.96
```

This is what I've worked out for myself:

- disk is essentially 100% busy servicing the sequential reads of the disk;
- rkB/s is pretty close to the 13.2MB/s that dd reported;
- rkB/s divided by r/s is 117kB, which is the same as the avgrq-sz figure (which is in sectors); I dare say iostat just does the same calculation.
- a 'blockdev --getra /dev/sda' tells me that the device has a readahead set of 256 sectors; this is pretty close to the 117kB average request size.

So I'm assuming that:

- dd is reading in blocks of 16KB;
- but Linux is promptly doing readahead reads of 128KB.

But things I don't understand include:

- 1000ms divided by the await of 23.77ms gives me a figure of 42 requests a second; yet the r/s is 103.40?
- Why would the avgqu-sz be anything other than 1?  My dd was a single-threaded process, the kernel would have been only invoking readahead one at a time?
- On the other hand, avgqu-sz * 1000ms / 23.77ms gives me 109 r/s, pretty close to the r/s that was reported.
- What are all of those merged requests?  rrqm/s is 12,030?!?!  I can't make sense of that in either 128kB readahead blocks or the 16kB user-level reads that dd was making.

I guess there are some basic things concerning modern disks and Linux of which I am totally ignorant.  :(  The avgqu-sz is probably the key - why would lookahead have more than one request in the queue at any time?